# Cómo usar el 100% del viewport en React?

Tags: css, reactjs, viewport

Soy nuevo con React y estoy intentando que mi página ocupe el 100% del viewport sin exito.

Así se ve la página:
[image: vista actual de la página]

Qué deberia modificar en el css del app?
Por el momento tengo esto

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
   }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias !

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy incompleta, por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega el código para construir un ejemplo mínimo y necesario

Comment: Ahi lo modifique, esta mejor asi ?

Comment: Es difícil dar una sugerencia o respuesta sin conocer la estructura de la aplicación. Específicamente cómo has estructurado el JSX en el archivo `App.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema, debes de ir al archivo **index.css**, este archivo vendría siendo el que maneje todo el css principal de tu aplicación, entonces cuando entres a ese archivo veras que tiene otro código fuente de css algo así:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 18px;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
   'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
   sans-serif;
   background: #1D976C;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #93F9B9, #1D976C);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #93F9B9, #1D976C); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
   

}

code {
 font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
   monospace;
}

Y Entonces en body, o en el inicio que empieza con 
* { 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 18px;
} 
agregas el **width: 100%;**
```

Comment: Era eso @AllisLove. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Con mucho gusto amigo.